# Nodejs receiving string instead of boolean

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send http request to node server with boolean value in the object.

I receive in node `req.body`:

```
somekey: "true"
```

instead of

```
somekey: true
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Also with int..

Comment: Need more information on your question.

Comment: Paste the code that you are using to send request.

Comment: what about `yourBool = JSON.parse(req.body.somekey);` - that should evaluate to boolean

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/74#issuecomment-69029334

Comment: @NullDev is there a way to automate it? Instead of writing this for each bool?

Comment: @Raz Yes, I made a small example below. Let me know if it worked :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) NPM package.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//You middleware should have this before the handlers.
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

EDIT:

This is what your AJAX request should look like. You're probably missing the `JSON.stringify` part for request body or not setting `Content-Type: application/json` in your request header. This works for me.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/hello/login',

    type: 'POST',

    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },

    data: JSON.stringify({
        somekey: true
    }),

    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
});
```

Comment: I already have it:
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

Comment: What code are you using to send the request? Please post it here.

Comment: I am just doing a standard HTTP request (ajax).. sending array of objects. no more than that.